# Как обратиться к методу объекта из колбэка в JS?

Tags: javascript

Вот у меня есть код:

```
class BaseInput{
    constructor(value){
        this.makeButtonVisible = null;
        this.makeButtonVisible = function(){
            alert(1234);
        };
        this.makeButtonInvisible = null;

        this._input = document.createElement('input');
        this._input.type = 'text';
        this._input.value = value;
        this._input.dataset.value = value;

        this._input.oninput = function(){
            if (this.value != this.dataset.value)
               BaseInput.makeButtonVisible();
            else
                alert(321);
        }

        document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(this._input);
    }
}
```

в `this._input.oninput` я добавляю функцию, которая должна обратиться к методам `makeButtonVisible` или `makeButtonInvisible` этого объекта

Comment: зачем вы сначала обнуляете `this.makeButtonVisible` а потом присваиваете функцию? Для каждого экземпляра запускается свой конструктор и такие штуки не нужны

Comment: это пока пишу, вообще другой класс должен присвоить эту функцию. Но если вы подскажете, как можно объявить свойство, не присвоив ему значение, чтобы присвоить ему значение можно было потом, то я буду очень благодарен))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    this._input.dataset.value = value;
    this._input.logic = this;

    this._input.oninput = function(e) {
        if (this.value != this.dataset.value)
            this.logic.makeButtonVisible();
        else
            alert(321);
    };
```

или

```
    this._input.dataset.value = value;

    this._input.oninput = (e) => {
        if (this._input.value != this._input.dataset.value)
            this.makeButtonVisible();
        else
            alert(321);
    };
```

или

```
    this._input.dataset.value = value;

    this._input.oninput = (function(e) {
        if (this._input.value != this._input.dataset.value)
            this.makeButtonVisible();
        else
            alert(321);
    }).bind(this);
```